# Scaffold Models based on Entity Framework - Validation Errors

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, visual-studio

I have my application configured to use a SQLRoleManager. I simply created the database, configured the web.config, and let the application create and populate the database tables.

I would like an admin view to preform some simple operations such as add and remove users. Thus, I have created an entity framework data context using the scaffolding wizard and directed it to build around the tables only. (did not check views and stored procedures).

The next thing i wished to do was to then scaffold the controller and view and eventual the model for this data. When I right click controllers I select the add controller with views using entity framework. I fill out the appropriate information selecting an empty class for the model.

[image]

I receive the following error which indicates the data is missing keys yet they are in fact defined on the database and in the entity model. Any thoughts as to where i am going wrong here? Do I need to pre build the model? I was hoping to have visual studio create these automatically.

[image]

**EDIT**

Again, the tables all have primary and foreign keys. I can confirm this from Sql Management Studio as well as the .edmx diagram. The bellow code was auto generated. Do i need to add keys?

**Context.edmx**

[image]

**UserRole_Context.tt > aspnet_Users.cs**

```
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// <auto-generated>
//     This code was generated from a template.
//
//     Manual changes to this file may cause unexpected behavior in your application.
//     Manual changes to this file will be overwritten if the code is regenerated.
// </auto-generated>
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------

namespace IDM.DAL
{
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public partial class aspnet_Users
{
    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2214:DoNotCallOverridableMethodsInConstructors")]
    public aspnet_Users()
    {
        this.aspnet_PersonalizationPerUser = new HashSet<aspnet_PersonalizationPerUser>();
        this.aspnet_Roles = new HashSet<aspnet_Roles>();
    }

    public System.Guid ApplicationId { get; set; }
    public System.Guid UserId { get; set; }
    public string UserName { get; set; }
    public string LoweredUserName { get; set; }
    public string MobileAlias { get; set; }
    public bool IsAnonymous { get; set; }
    public System.DateTime LastActivityDate { get; set; }

    public virtual aspnet_Applications aspnet_Applications { get; set; }
    public virtual aspnet_Membership aspnet_Membership { get; set; }
    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
    public virtual ICollection<aspnet_PersonalizationPerUser> aspnet_PersonalizationPerUser { get; set; }
    public virtual aspnet_Profile aspnet_Profile { get; set; }
    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
    public virtual ICollection<aspnet_Roles> aspnet_Roles { get; set; }
}
}
```

**UserRole_Context.Context.cs**

```
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// <auto-generated>
//     This code was generated from a template.
//
//     Manual changes to this file may cause unexpected behavior in your application.
//     Manual changes to this file will be overwritten if the code is regenerated.
// </auto-generated>
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------

namespace IDM.DAL
{
using System;
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure;

public partial class IDMEntities : DbContext
{
    public IDMEntities()
        : base("name=IDMEntities")
    {
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        throw new UnintentionalCodeFirstException();
    }

    public virtual DbSet<aspnet_Applications> aspnet_Applications { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<aspnet_Membership> aspnet_Membership { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<aspnet_Paths> aspnet_Paths { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<aspnet_PersonalizationAllUsers> aspnet_PersonalizationAllUsers { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<aspnet_PersonalizationPerUser> aspnet_PersonalizationPerUser { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<aspnet_Profile> aspnet_Profile { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<aspnet_Roles> aspnet_Roles { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<aspnet_SchemaVersions> aspnet_SchemaVersions { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<aspnet_Users> aspnet_Users { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<aspnet_WebEvent_Events> aspnet_WebEvent_Events { get; set; }
}
}
```

**Connection String**

```
<add name="IDMEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/DAL.UserRole_Context.csdl|res://*/DAL.UserRole_Context.ssdl|res://*/DAL.UserRole_Context.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=*******;initial catalog=IDM;integrated security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" /></connectionStrings>
```

Comment: You are getting Entity telling you the error: "I have no keys bro".  Give the database their keys and free them from the possible anarchy of heaped data.  If you are doing code first you need to set a field matching the class name with '(classname)Id' or 'Id' or else add a 'Key' attribute to the property.  If you are doing database first, ensure you tables have primary keys.  EF does not play as far as I know with heaps and needs keyed tables.

Comment: @djangojazz That is just it. I am doing database first. All tables have a PK but i am still getting this error.

Comment: Since it says `unable to retrieve metadata`, my guess is that you're trying to generate the model using an application user instead of an admin/sa user.

Comment: However, since you also said you're using an EDMX, you could be missing the part of the connection string that is similar to `metadata=res://*Impl.Entities.SecurityModel.csdl|res://*Impl.Entities.SecurityModel.ssdl|res://*Impl.Entities.SecurityModel.msl`, where the names match your models.

Comment: @Eris the connection string has the metadata filled out for the entire model. It does not have one for the individual tables, Could that be the issue?